# SQL select rows with max repetition betwen two dates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have three tables Books, Debit and Client.

1. Books (Id, Title, ...)
2. Debit (BooksID, ClientId, BorrowingDate,....)
3. Client (Id, Name, ...)

I need SQL query that will return
a book that is most times rented out, between two dates.
Dates will be passed as parameters to query.

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
SELECT * FROM Books INNER JOIN Debit ON Books.Id = Debit.BooksID WHERE BorrowingDate >= @StartDate AND BorrowingDate <= @EndDate
```

If you edit in an example of what you would like the output to look like I can redefine the above query to help you get what you want.

And for the record, Adrian is right; it is generally better to make an attempt yourself and come to us with a problem, rather than asking SO to solve the problem for you. But hopefully what I have here will get you started. Welcome to SO! :)

**Edit**

It also just occurred to me that you might be looking for the book which was rented out most number of times between your two dates... If so, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Books.* FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS DebitCount, BooksID FROM Debit WHERE BorrowingDate >= @StartDate AND BorrowingDate <= @EndDate GROUP BY BooksID
) Debits INNER JOIN Books ON Books.ID = Debits.BooksID
ORDER BY DebitCount DESC
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The query...

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM (
    SELECT BooksID, COUNT(*) AS C
    FROM Debit
    WHERE BorrowingDate BETWEEN @min_date and @max_date
    GROUP BY BooksID
)
ORDER BY C DESC
```

...will yield one row containing the `BooksID` and number of rents of the book that has been rented most times between `@min_date` and `@max_date`.

You can later easily JOIN with `Books` if you need more than just `BooksID`.

Comment: +1 Because even though we arrived at a nearly identical answer, you've introduced me to the `BETWEEN` operator!